# Intersect array empty value if it will not be executed

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

if the array $same_white_pemasang or $same_black_pemasang empty value, then the return value will be ignored?

for $implodeWhiteJenisPemasang

```
$inputWhiteJenisPemasang = $verifikator['whiteJenisPemasang'];
$dataWhiteJenisPemasang = array();
foreach ($inputWhiteJenisPemasang as $bacaDataWhiteJenisPemasang) {
    if ($bacaDataWhiteJenisPemasang != "") { //jika inputnya kosong maka tidak akan dieksekusi
        $dataWhiteJenisPemasang[] = $bacaDataWhiteJenisPemasang;
    }
}
$implodeWhiteJenisPemasang = implode(", ", $dataWhiteJenisPemasang);
```

for $implodeBlackJenisPemasang

```
$inputBlackJenisPemasang = $verifikator['blackJenisPemasang'];
$dataBlackJenisPemasang = array();
foreach ($inputBlackJenisPemasang as $bacaDataBlackJenisPemasang) {
    if ($bacaDataBlackJenisPemasang != "") { //jika inputnya kosong maka tidak akan dieksekusi
        $dataBlackJenisPemasang[] = $bacaDataBlackJenisPemasang;
    }
}
$implodeBlackJenisPemasang = implode(", ", $dataBlackJenisPemasang);
```

array intersect

```
$same_white_pemasang = explode(', ', $implodeWhiteJenisPemasang);
$same_black_pemasang = explode(', ', $implodeBlackJenisPemasang);
if ($same_white_pemasang != "" && $same_black_pemasang != null) {
    $cekPemasang = array_intersect($same_black_pemasang, $same_white_pemasang);
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking the `$same_white_pemasang` and `$same_black_pemasang` against `""` (they're not strings) or `null` (they're not `null`, just empty), you'll want to check whether the array is empty, using the `empty()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: can you tell me about coding is correct?